# problemas con pdfMake y html-to-pdfmake al imprimir listas

Tags: angular, pdf

Estoy intentando generar un pdf desde una consulta a una base de datos, donde la información tiene código HTML, como listas. `<p>DDDD</p><ol><li>asdasdas</li><li>asdasdasd</li><li>asdasdasd</li></ol><ul><li>sdasdasd</li></ul>`

luego de instalar pdfmake y html-to-pdfmake, los importo en mi componente.ts

```
const pdfMake = require('node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake')
const pdfFonts = require('node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts')
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs
const htmlToPdfmake = require('html-to-pdfmake')
```

en algun momento mando a llamar al metodo donde se genera crea mi pdf

```
savePDF() {
    console.log(this.reConsulta)

    const documentDefinition = {
      pageSize: 'A5',
      pageOrientation: 'landscape',
      pageMargins: [5, 100, 5, 10],

      content: [
        { text: htmlToPdfmake(this.reConsulta.medicamentos) },
        { text: htmlToPdfmake(this.reConsulta.metodo), absolutePosition: { x: 320, y: 100 } },
      ],
    }

    pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).open()
  }
```

en este momento `this.reConsulta.medicamentos` tiene el valor de la lista anterior `<p>DDDD</p><ol><li>asdasdas</li><li>asdasdasd</li><li>asdasdasd</li></ol><ul><li>sdasdasd</li></ul>`

pero cdo crea el pdf no se muestra la lista, sin embargo otras etiquetas html como `<b></b>` `<i></i>` se formatean sin problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de buscar y consultar algo mas la bibliografía, así como los desarrolladores de las librerías, el problema quedo resulto.

El problema se generaba en el momento de crear las columnas con pdfMake. El código corregido debe quedar de esta manera para que funcione.

```
  savePDF() {

    const documentDefinition = {
      pageSize: 'A5',
      pageOrientation: 'landscape',
      pageMargins: [20, 100, 20, 10],

      content: [
        {
          columns: [
            {stack: htmlToPdfmake(this.reConsulta.medicamentos),            },
            { stack: htmlToPdfmake(this.reConsulta.metodo) },
          ],
          columnGap: 5,
        },
      ],
    }

    pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).open()
  }
}
```